# וועלען בענטשען or וועלין בענטשין

Tags: yiddish, spelling-variants, zimun

I'm fairly competent in speaking Yiddish, in fact, most of friends, family, and teachers consider me a fluent speaker. However, I noticed an interesting difference between two siddurim of mine.

In my Artscroll siddur, Zimun in Birkas Hamazon begins as follows:

> [רבותי מיר וועלען בענטשען [רבותי נברך

But in my Siddur Tehillas Hashem by Kehos, Zimun looks like this:

> רבותי מיר וועל**ין** בענטש**ין**

What's the reason for the difference in spelling? Why does the Siddur Tehillas Hashem say מיר וועלין בענטשין when the Artscroll says מיר וועלען בענטשען? From my experience with Yiddish, Artscroll appears to be right in this case because I learned Yiddish that way. Is it a difference between ליטוויש and חסידישע Yiddish?

Comment: Yiddish has no formal orthography. Furthermore, grammatically, it whould be וויר וואָלע/ין בענטשן, rather than מיר וואָלע/ין בענטשן

Comment: You could also email Artscroll and Kehot to see why they spelled it that way

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt See why did you spell vellen as völlen? Dialect?

Comment: In German (and presumably Western Yiddish/Jüdisch) it is wollen, rather than wellen. Thus I spelled it the way I'd pronounce it, according to my understanding of the orthography.

Comment: Hmmm...interesting. I guess from your username I could've guessed you were a יעקע.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Those *siddurim* represent Eastern-European Yiddish, and so can't reasonably be expected to use German/Western Yiddish orthography (do you know that Western Yiddish actually used Wir and wöllen?).  The reason for those differences in spelling is because that ען/ין is really a representation of a "syllabic n", that is, there's no vowel there.  That's why YIVO spelling recommends װעלן.

Comment: @magicker72, I don't disagree with your assessment of orthography. However the *mir*/*wir* dichotomy is still a valid grammatical question.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt The OP wasn't asking about the pronoun, just about the spelling of װעל(ע/י/∅)ן and בענטש(ע/י/∅)ן (and that part of my comment was directed at the OP, sorry).

Comment: @magicker72, No problem

Comment: The shortened en is similar to in.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I'm assuming also the "w"s in front of "wir" and "wöllen" make a v-sound like in German. Correct, or am I getting more confused and there's actually a w-sound in German Yiddish?

Comment: Ezra, it's the same sound as in German. Why else would it be written וו in Hebrew, when בֿ or פֿ are often used to render German letter v?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The various spellings are trying to get at a vowel-less pronunciation of the final syllable: the [syllabic n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllabic_consonant) (for example, some English dialects pronounce "button" as "but'n", with a syllabic n at the end).  From Uriel Weinreich's [dictionary](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43653&st=&pgnum=829), in the section on non-YIVO-standard orthography:

> a superfluous ע is sometimes written before final ל or ן to mark their syllabicity.

The same occurs (although less common) with a י instead of an ע (perhaps modeled on the feminine suffix ־ין, where the י is written but not pronounced).  YIVO standardized spelling writes your words as װעלן ("veln") and בענטשן ("bentshn"), without any vowel before the ן.  See [here](http://www.leagueforyiddish.org/styior.html) for more details.